# The output is always 0.0

Tags: java

The problem is the series just results in 0.0. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n, a, x;
        double S = 0.0;
        System.out.println("Input value of n, a and x");
        n = sc.nextInt();
        a = sc.nextInt();
        x = sc.nextInt();
        for(int i = 1;i >= n; i = i + 1) {
            S = (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Math.pow(x,i),i)+1)/Math.pow(a,i));
        }
        System.out.println("Series = "+S);

    }
}
```

I was expecting it to work and my teachers said it was correct, but it results in 0.0.

Comment: Hint: try logging every time your for loop body runs... and check your loop conditions.

Comment: Just as a hint: Instead of writing i=i+1 you can write i++ which incremts i by 1.

Comment: Check how the condition for a foor loop work. And test your loop on a paper by writing down what happens when n is 0,1,2 for example.

Second check the body of your loop. By assigning S everytime (even if the loop would work as you expect) only the last calcuated S would matter, and all previous runs of your loop would not change anyhting.

Comment: Debugging is a useful skill. For those who want to become a professional software developer, or otherwise regularly develop software, it will be a *necessary* skill. A debugger should be included with an IDE.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging

Comment: thanks yall ill start to work on debugging and testing forloop, thanks for the i++ tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the for loop, the condition `i >= n` should be reversed. If your n is higher than 1, the loop is never entered.